# Make application available to all users

Tags: linux, installation, redhat, sudo

I am the sudo user **(main_user)** of my server (redhat8) and have many user accounts **(user1, user2,....)**.
I can run installed application in server using **main_user** account but the other users are not able to execute the program or run the application.

** I have installed the applications/programs from **main_user** account which is not a root user but having sudo previlages.

What can be done to make the application and programs available to other users as well.

**What I tried:**

I have made alias in  both **./bashrc** and **profile.d/all_user.sh**, and source them but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement `sudo`. First in `/etc/sudoers` file add line like:

```
user1,user2,user2    ALL=/path/to/the/program
```

If the users above are in specific group you can add something like:

```
%usergroup   ALL=/path/to/the/program
```

And run the program like:

```
sudo -u main_user /path/to/the/program
```

Comment: Hard luck with this too :(